# Paramaterize Case Statement Using ODBC

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I am selecting data from an MS SQL DB using a similar query to this:

```
$result = odbc_prepare(
   $connection, 
   "SELECT 
      t1.id, thumbnail, description, brand, vendor, 
      case 
         when ".implode(' AND ', $exactSearchTermDesc)." then 1 
         else 0 
      end as exactdescriptionmatch, 
      case 
         when ".implode(' AND ', $exactSearchTermMarkDesc)."". $exactThesaurusMarkDesc ." 
         then 1 else 0 
      end as exactcontentmatch, 
      case 
         when ".implode(' AND ', $searchTermDesc)."" . $thesaurusDesc ." then 1 
         else 0 
      end as descriptionmatch, 
      case 
         when ".implode(' AND ', $searchTermMarkDesc)."". $thesaurusMarkDesc ." then 1 
         else 0 
      end as contentmatch 
   FROM Martin.dbo.item_search"
);
odbc_execute($result);
```

How do I parameterize the variables in the case statements?

I tried, for example, just trying to paramaterize the first variable with this to no avail...

```
$exactSearchTermDesc = implode(' AND ', $exactSearchTermDesc);
$result = odbc_prepare(
   $connection, 
   "SELECT 
      t1.id, thumbnail, description, brand, vendor, 
      case when ? then 1 else 0 end as exactdescriptionmatch, 
      case when ".implode(' AND ', $exactSearchTermMarkDesc)."". $exactThesaurusMarkDesc ." then 1 else 0 end as exactcontentmatch, 
      case when ".implode(' AND ', $searchTermDesc)."" . $thesaurusDesc ." then 1 else 0 end as descriptionmatch, 
      case when ".implode(' AND ', $searchTermMarkDesc)."". $thesaurusMarkDesc ." then 1 else 0 end as contentmatch 
   FROM Martin.dbo.item_search"
);
odbc_execute($result array($exactSearchTermDesc));
```

The variables are as below. $terms is the user input.

```
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $terms);
            $exactSearchTermDesc = array();
            $exactSearchTermMarkDesc = array();
            $searchTermDesc = array();
            $searchTermMarkDesc = array();
            foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
                $term = trim($term);
                if (!empty($term)) {
                    $exactSearchTermDesc[] = "description LIKE '$term %'";
                    $exactSearchTermMarkDesc[] = "contains(marketingDescription, '$term')";
                    $searchTermDesc[] = "description LIKE '%$term%'";
                    $searchTermMarkDesc[] = "marketingDescription LIKE '%$term%'";
                    $searchTermVendor[] = "vendor LIKE '%$term%'";
                }
            }

$exactThesaurusDesc = " Or " . implode(' AND ', $exactThesaurusDesc); 
                $exactThesaurusMarkDesc = " Or " . implode(' AND ', $exactThesaurusMarkDesc);
                $thesaurusDesc = " Or " . implode(' AND ', $thesaurusDesc);
                $thesaurusMarkDesc = " Or " . implode(' AND ', $thesaurusMarkDesc);
                $thesaurusVendor = " Or " . implode(' AND ', $thesaurusVendor);
```

Comment: The query works fine in the code.  I just extracted the part I figured one would need to explain how to parameterize it...

Comment: Can you possibly show values of `$` variables? It is very important to know since you cannot parameterize identifiers like table or column names, only number values or string literals. Your query could work if all variables contain column names and hence no parameterization of literal values is needed.

Comment: What happens if you build the query outside of odbc_prepare and then just include the whole built query as a variable?

Comment: @Parfait Updated!

Comment: @Parfait Those are the exact same, I am concatenating SQL pieces.

Comment: This is getting pretty dense with quite a bit dynamic SQL (ideally, data should be dynamic component not SQL). In a separate block can you post what a full SQL string (with PHP variables rendered, redact as needed) to see a typical query call. There may be a more efficient way to avoid this long SQL build for each term.

Answer (score 1):

Consider re-factoring your SQL process. Rather than piecing together dynamic SQL components at application layer (i.e., PHP) that can impact readability and maintainability, consider multiple self-joins to a temp table of *terms* with below definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tmp_terms (
  id IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  term VARCHAR(255),
  thesauraus_indicator BIT
)
```

Specifically, run an aggregate query across joined matches where `MIN` returns 0 or 1. With this approach, the ***same*** SQL query is maintained but the underlying *terms* populated by PHP will be the dynamic component.

Below runs the non-thesaurus part of previous `CASE` logic. Also, since [`CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) cannot use another column but only a literal value, `JOIN` expressions use `LIKE` with the leading and trailing wildcard.

```sql
SELECT 
   i.id, i.thumbnail, i.description, i.brand, i.vendor, 
   MIN(case 
           when exact_desc.term IS NOT NULL
           then 1 
           else 0 
       end) AS exact_description_match, 
   MIN(case 
           when market_match.term IS NOT NULL
           then 1 
           else 0 
       end) AS market_match, 
   MIN(case 
           when desc_match.term IS NOT NULL
           then 1 
          else 0 
       end) AS desc_match, 
   MIN(case 
           when vendor_match.term IS NOT NULL
           then 1 
           else 0 
       end) AS vendor_match 

FROM Martin.dbo.item_search i
LEFT JOIN tmp_terms exact_desc
   ON i.description LIKE CONCAT(exact_desc.term, ' %')
   AND exact_desc.thesaurus_indicator = 0
LEFT JOIN tmp_terms market_match
   ON i.marketingDescription LIKE CONCAT('%', market_match.term, '%')
   AND market_match.thesaurus_indicator = 0
LEFT JOIN tmp_terms desc_match
   ON i.description LIKE CONCAT('%', desc_match.term, '%')
   AND desc_match.thesaurus_indicator = 0
LEFT JOIN tmp_terms vendor_match
   ON i.vendor LIKE CONCAT('%', vendor_match.term, '%')
   AND vendor_match.thesaurus_indicator = 0

GROUP BY i.id, i.thumbnail, i.description, i.brand, i.vendor
```

To integrate the thesaurus match, use `UNION` in CTE or subquery before aggregation in outer query.

```sql
WITH sub AS
   (SELECT 
       i.id, i.thumbnail, i.description, i.brand, i.vendor, 
       exact_desc.term AS exact_desc_term, market_match.term AS market_match_term, 
       desc_match.term AS desc_match_term, vendor_match.term AS vendor_match_term

    FROM Martin.dbo.item_search i
    LEFT JOIN tmp_terms exact_desc
       ON i.description LIKE CONCAT(exact_desc.term, ' %')
       AND exact_desc.thesaurus_indicator = 0
    LEFT JOIN tmp_terms market_match
       ON i.marketingDescription LIKE CONCAT('%', market_match.term, '%')
       AND market_match.thesaurus_indicator = 0
    LEFT JOIN tmp_terms desc_match
       ON i.description LIKE CONCAT('%', desc_match.term, '%')
       AND desc_match.thesaurus_indicator = 0
    LEFT JOIN tmp_terms vendor_match
       ON i.vendor LIKE CONCAT('%', vendor_match.term, '%')
       AND vendor_match.thesaurus_indicator = 0

    UNION

    SELECT 
       i.id, i.thumbnail, i.description, i.brand, i.vendor, 
       th_exact_desc.term, th_market_match.term, 
       th_desc_match.term, th_vendor_match.term

    LEFT JOIN tmp_terms th_exact_desc
       ON i.description LIKE CONCAT(th_exact_desc.term, ' %')
       AND th_exact_match.thesaurus_indicator = 1
    LEFT JOIN tmp_terms th_market_match
       ON i.marketingDescription LIKE CONCAT('%', th_market_match.term, '%')
       AND th_market_match.thesaurus_indicator = 1
    LEFT JOIN tmp_terms th_desc_match
       ON i.description LIKE CONCAT('%', th_desc_match.term, '%')
       AND th_desc_match.thesaurus_indicator = 1
    LEFT JOIN tmp_terms th_vendor_match
       ON i.vendor LIKE CONCAT('%', th_vendor_match.term, '%')
       AND th_vendor_match.thesaurus_indicator = 1
   )

SELECT sub.id, sub.thumbnail, sub.description, sub.brand, sub.vendor, 
       MIN(case 
               when sub.exact_desc_term IS NOT NULL
               then 1 
               else 0 
           end) AS exact_description_match, 
       MIN(case 
               when sub.market_match_term IS NOT NULL
               then 1 
               else 0 
           end) AS market_match, 
       MIN(case 
               when sub.desc_match_term IS NOT NULL
               then 1 
              else 0 
           end) AS desc_match, 
       MIN(case 
               when sub.vendor_match_term IS NOT NULL
               then 1 
               else 0 
           end) AS vendor_match 
FROM sub
GROUP BY sub.id, sub.thumbnail, sub.description, sub.brand, sub.vendor
```

Note: Above queries may need adjustment to final end use needs and testing. Performance may vary depending on number of search terms. But ultimately, the concept is to interact with data in sets and not long concatenated `CASE WHEN...` logic that grows with search terms.

---

Finally, in PHP simply clean out and populate the temp table with new values using parameterization and run any of the above final query:

```php
odbc_exec($connection, "DELETE FROM tmp_terms");

$stmt = odbc_prepare($connection,
                     "INSERT INTO tmp_terms (term, thesaurus_indicator) 
                      VALUES (?, ?)");

// NON-THESAURUS TERMS
foreach($search_terms as $t) {
   odbc_execute($stmt, array($t, 0));
}

// THESAURUS TERMS
foreach($th_search_terms as $t) {
   odbc_execute($stmt, array($t, 1));
}

// RUN FINAL SELECT QUERY
$result = odbc_exec($connection, "my_final_above_query");

while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
         for($i=1; $i<=odbc_num_fields($result); $i++){
             // ... odbc_result($result,$i);
    }
}
```